# Wait Until is not present, not working in Selenium C#

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to test if a loading spinner is still on the page, so when it disappears I can check the other elements, but if I use something like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.Driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
wait.Until(driver => !driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(css)).Displayed);
```

It throws `NoSuchElementException`, I've had similar error when I try to check if element exists, without using `!` and also it would throw an error in some other parts of the code.

It seems that the `Until` is not working properly, since it waits 2 minutes to later throw an exception, and the element is just there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `FindElement` will throw an exception when an element is not found, which is *different* to an element being found *but* not being displayed.

`WebDriverWait` will allow you to specify exceptions you can ignore. So:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.Driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
```

Aother option would be to be a bit more defensive in your code. Elements have multiple states, so something like a try/catch would work.

One final option would be to use `ExpectedConditions` (a set of 'basic' conditions handcrafted for you to use):

```
wait.Until(driver => ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(css));
```

Comment: Downvote? Care to comment or just want to blindly downvote and move on?

Comment: Used the last one approach and worked :)
I would just remove the lambda expression and use only:
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(css));

Comment: I used your solution combined with the FindElements and checking if the Count of elements are zero, FindElement throws exception and FindElements not.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait till the element totally disappears from the DOM. You can use:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("your Xpath here")));
```

`Element Exists` Is very good for checking pop-up messages existence on UI